# EC2 Unable to install httpd

Tags: amazon-ec2, httpd

Trying to setup wordpress in EC2. found several tutorials in web and tried. their are few steps to setup apache, php, mysql. one thing is install httpd following command

```
yum install httpd
```

But I am failed to install getting following message

```
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available. 
Nothing to do
```

how to do install httpd and running apache server

After running yum repolist enabled I got this result

```
repolist: 0
```

Comment: Can you run `yum repolist enabled` to show which repositories are enabled?  Please update your question with the results.

Comment: after running yum repolist enabled it shows
repolist: 0

Comment: If you're this used to CentOS, why not use CentOS? Amazon even has their own CentOS-based "Amazon Linux" AMIs.

Answer (score 5):

Your repos are either empty or inactive.

What's the contents of the directory /etc/yum.repos.d ?

Are you running Amazon Linux or some other Linux?  Run `cat /etc/issue.net`.

Update:

OP is using Ubuntu, not a RHEL-based distro.

So, in that case, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

If you follow instructions from the web, look for Ubuntu-specific ones, rather than ones that pertain to RedHat-based systems.

Note that the Apache package for Ubuntu is called "apache2", not "httpd".

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I cant find yum.repos.d in etc

Comment: Oh.  You should not be using "yum".  That's the RedHat/CentOS/AmazonLinux package management tool.  You should be using "apt-get".  Let me update my Answer with information on what to do.

Comment: Thanks cjc. I tried apt-get here is result

E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Prasanna Correct, the package is named "apache2" in Ubuntu, not "httpd". See the last line of my updated Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package "httpd" does not exist in your repository. Try searching via yum search, e.g. `yum search apache` or `yum search http`.

Another approach could be searching the internet for a CentOS/Suse/RHEL mirror and download the apache packages directly (or enhancing the list of your repos).

Btw, maybe this link will be an additional help: [1](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=914893)

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure apache is not already installed.

`httpd -v`